# HTTP or HTTPS - Open Source Web App

Tags: http, https, gitlab, open-source

We are developing a web app that currently support HTTPs or HTTP.  In production, the app should absolutely use HTTPs.  We also want to make it open source on GitHub, where contributors would be able to run the web app with their on servers on localhost.  They won't be able to test HTTPS without using a cert and server private key.  We don't want to put our server private key in version control. How do open source projects that allow HTTPS usually handle this?  We were thinking of allowing HTTP just for testing.

Comment: I'd put the sensitive info in a properties file that is not pushed. People can test using their own data by creating a propeties file with defined properties. Otherwise fall back to http.